# Handling Screen Idling and Suspension

Tags: winrt-xaml

Just need to know what to handle for this situation:

Case(1) When user is not doing anything on the screen for a period of time

The system will suspend the app? Is this what causes suspension? This means nothing will be processed in the background?

How to handle this case that I want the process continues when app is left unattended (example : Using GPS )

----- Update

Need some confirmations for the following scenarios:

1) App is launched and user navigates from mainPage to other Page AND left the Tablet alone for a period of time and user did not interact with the Screen.

In this case, this will cause the Physical screen turn to black color screen. Is this means app Suspension or something else?

2) How Lock Screen or Screen Lock work or when it will happen. how different is screenLock from above question(1)? or they are the same thing?

Screen Lock will cause App Suspension?

3) When user presses the home button (Hardware button) on the tablet, this will cause App Suspension or termination?

4) In Windows Phone, there are these to detect and prevent Screen Lock and run the app :
a.The UserIdleDetectionMode property 
b.The ApplicationIdleDetectionMode property

Can these be used in WinRT App? or how to handle this like WP in WinRT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the app is the foreground app and the screen is active, it won't be suspended.  Apps get suspended primarily for moving to the background.  This wouldn't be just idle time, but could be if something like a lockscreen/screensaver comes on and the window is no longer active.

You could know this immediately by looking at Window.Activated events, but in this case a de-activated window (assuming it was the only and primary one for the app) would likely mean it went to he background and thus in queue for suspend.

And yes, once suspended, no code is running *from the app* -- if you wanted background code to run you'd need to use a background task (see MSDN samples for an example).